# simultaneous diagonalization of set matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, gap

I have a set of integral square invertible symmetric matrices $A_i$ with $A_i^2=I$ (so also $A_i A_i^T=I$). The matrices commute. I'd like to map them simultaneously to a set of diagonal matrices $D_i$ using a matrix $C : C A_i C^{T}= D_i$. The $D_i$'s are the diagonals of the eigenvalues of $A_i$ in some particular order (I know the $D_i$'s already). I know simultaneous diagonalization isn't in general easy, but maybe this special case has a clever solution. Also interested if there's anything in GAP that might help.

In this older post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46949/is-there-a-built-in-procedure-for-simultaneous-diagonalization-of-a-set-of-commu the accepted answer says that you can take the eigenvectors of a "random linear combination" of the matrices. My matrices are diagonalizable so the part about geometric/arithmetic multiplicity applies. This approach is not enough for what I'm doing; there's no guarantee that the linear combination happens to be a right one; also the probability of success doesn't seem that high for what I tried.

Comment: is the $C$ supposed to be a real orthogonal matrix?  It isn't clear to me what the field (ring?) is supposed to be here.  That said, since these are symmetric involutions, my sense is it's probably prudent to solve the equivalent problem using orthogonal projection matrices $B_i := \frac{1}{2}\big(A+I\big)$

Comment: The field is the reals; the matrices just happen to be integral. So $C$ is a real orthogonal matrix. How would moving to $B_i$'s help?

Comment: what kind of complexity can you live with? Both $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s are nice for complementary reasons. A relatively simple *divide and conquer* algorithm would be: select $B_k$ with trace $r$ closest to $\frac{n}{2}$ i.e. $r := \min_k \big\vert \text{trace}\big(B_k\big)- \frac{n}{2}\big\vert$ and let $\mathbf B$ be have first $r$ vectors be orthonormal basis for its $B_k$'s image then vectors $\geq r+1$ orthonormal basis vectors for $\ker B_k$. Now consider $A_i':=\mathbf B^TA_i\mathbf B   $ and recurse on the $r\times r$ and $(n-r)\times (n-r)$ subproblems

Comment: at this point any algorithm is ok. The $A_i$'s have many special properties so once I know the algorithm I think I can optimize it. Also all $A_i$'s have $n/2,+1$ and $n/2,-1$ eigenvalues, so all $B_i$'s have rank $n/2$. I'm not sure I follow the recursion part : $A_i'$ is still $nxn$...can you please describe in a more detail.

Comment: every $A_i'$ is block diagonal with a leading $r\times r$ block and the other block $(n-r)\times (n-r)$.  Though it seems extra nice with $r =\frac{n}{2}$.  You divide and conquer on the two blocks i.e. first recurse on the $r\times r$ blocks which form a group,  You can verify this directly with matrix multiplication, either abstractly or for your specific matrices.  An optional extra nice interpretation:  The $A_i$'s form a finite group $G$ and $\ker B_i$ and $\text{im } B_i$ are $G$-invariant subspaces (this is essentially the lead-up to Schur's Lemma).

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see how this works; but it seems that the number of operations will double every time at each step in the recursion : process $A_1$, then process two blocks from $A_2'$ then process 4 subbblocks from $A_3''$,...is this right? unless there's a relation between the subblocks that I'm missing.

Comment: if you're going to estimate big Oh complexity: note the work to come up with a kernel and image basis is a function of matrix size which shrinks at each stage. As is often the case: the key issue, is how 'balanced' your tree is -- if you can find an $r$ at each stage roughly half of the dimension, then the trees are roughly balanced and you have $\log_2(n)$ recursion calls. Ignoring that work is less at each stage (i.e. using your doubling argument) the most intensive stage would have a $2^{\log_2(n)}=n$ work multiplier.  Unbalanced trees could be problematic. I leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simultaneous diagonalization of a set of commuting matrices is quite easy -- since the matrices commute they preserve each others eigenspaces. Thus find a eigenvector basis for the first matrix, and then split each eigenspace using the second matrix and so on. The following GAP code does this:

```
# Arguments: Field, matrixlist
SimultaneousDiagonalization:=function(F,mats)
local bas,m,nbas,b,c,start,j,ev,eigen,ran,block;
  # basis so far: List of eigenspace bases
  bas:=[IdentityMat(Length(mats[1]),F)];
  for m in mats do
    nbas:=[];
    #rewrite m wrt the eigenspaces so far
    b:=Concatenation(bas);
    c:=b*m/b;
    start:=0;
    for j in bas do
      # now split this eigenspace
      ran:=[start+1..start+Length(j)];
      block:=c{ran}{ran};
      ev:=Eigenvalues(F,block);
      eigen:=List(ev,x->NullspaceMat(block-x*block^0));
      # and store the new spaces to use instead
      Append(nbas,List(eigen,k->k*j));
      start:=start+Length(j);
    od;
    bas:=nbas;
  od;
  return bas;
end;
```

It returns a list of bases of the common eigenspaces. Thus, if the result is `B` then with `C:=Concatenation(B)`, you have that $C\cdot A_i\cdot C^{-1}$ is diagonal. To get an orthogonal matrix, you simply run Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization on each of these eigenspace bases.

The result often will be ugly, since GAP does not naturally work with real numbers, thus I'm not attempting to do so.

Comment: this is very nice...it worked right off the bat. The matrices I'm working with have special properties so the $C$ coming back is already orthogonal in the cases I tried so far; in fact all its entries are +1,-1,0. Thanks for your code.

Comment: Cool code! Is there a simple way to alter this to simultaneously block diagonalize (as much as possible) a set of non-commuting matrices (say the generators for a finite matrix group)?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira not with this code.  What you are asking for is a composition series of the module (which one can compute but different methods)

Comment: Ya so if I was trying to simultaneously block diagonalize a finite group of matrices over a finite field then I would use meataxe I guess? But since I'm interested in finite groups of complex matrices I'm not sure how to do this. Am I just lazy/confused and this is explained somewhere obvious in the GAP manual? Or is it actually pretty complicated to get a basis for the decomposition of a finite complex matrix group into a direct sum of irreducible representations?

Comment: The MeatAxe per se is field agnostic, just GAP's implementation has some places where it is finite-field specific. Do you want to ask a separate queston in which you post the matrices of your group?